# Separating the front-end and the API server in JHipster with OAuth2 does not work

Tags: oauth-2.0, jhipster

I created a simple JHipster 6.2.0 Angular app with OAuth2 and I also generated a client side application separately. Besides I created a docker for Keycloak using the keycloak.yml 
that comes with JHipster, but with some more parameters for PostgreSQL as database.

Run both applications on the same context and by default, as expected, everything work will fine.

In order to run both applications on different contexts, as it is said at https://www.jhipster.tech/separating-front-end-and-api/, I set SERVER_API_URL = `'http://localhost:8080'` on client side in webpack.common.js.

In this scenario, in dev mode:

1. I start up backend application inside my IDE (IntelliJ)
2. I execute *npm start* to start up client
3. In a Chrome browser, I call http://localhost:9000
4. Click on "sign in" link
5. Fill the Keycloak's login window with admin credentials

Instead of receiving a window with text 'You are logged in as user "admin".', I go back to the same home page again, with "sign in" link. So I cannot complete the sign in process.

In this scenario I never reach *api/account*, method public UserDTO getAccount(Principal principal) on AccountResource. In Chrome Network tab I see two calls to account, both of then with Status Code 302 Ok.

Any ideas in order to solve this problem will be appreciated.

[api/account call image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdzHt.png)

**curl (cmd)**

```
curl "http://localhost:8080/api/account" -H "Referer: http://localhost:9000/" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36" --compressed
```

**.yo-rc.json front-end**

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "nativeLanguage": "es"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "6.2.0",
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "baseName": "clientlauncher",
    "useSass": true,
    "clientPackageManager": "npm",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "clientTheme": "none",
    "clientThemeVariant": "",
    "authenticationType": "oauth2",
    "cacheProvider": "no",
    "databaseType": "postgres",
    "devDatabaseType": "postgres",
    "prodDatabaseType": "postgres",
    "testFrameworks": [],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "entitySuffix": "",
    "dtoSuffix": "DTO",
    "otherModules": [],
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "es",
    "languages": ["es", "en"],
    "blueprints": [],
    "skipServer": true
  }
}
```

**.yo-rc.json back-end**

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "com.xxx.yyy",
      "nativeLanguage": "es"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "6.2.0",
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "baseName": "smartoee",
    "packageName": "com.xxx.yyy",
    "packageFolder": "com/xxx/yyy",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "oauth2",
    "cacheProvider": "ehcache",
    "enableHibernateCache": true,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "prodDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": false,
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "useSass": true,
    "clientPackageManager": "npm",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "clientTheme": "none",
    "clientThemeVariant": "",
    "testFrameworks": [],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "entitySuffix": "",
    "dtoSuffix": "DTO",
    "otherModules": [],
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "es",
    "languages": ["es", "en"],
    "blueprints": []
  }
}
```

**Security in application.yml**

```
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          oidc:
            issuer-uri: http://192.168.0.159:9080/auth/realms/jhipster
        registration:
          oidc:
            client-id: web_app
            client-secret: web_app
```

**CORS in application-dev.yml:**

```
  cors:
    allowed-origins: '*'
    allowed-methods: '*'
    allowed-headers: '*'
    exposed-headers: 'Authorization,Link,X-Total-Count'
    allow-credentials: true
    max-age: 1800   

I also tried, but it didn't work:   
  cors:
    allowed-origins:
      - http://localhost:8080
      - http://localhost:9000
      - http://localhost:9060
      - http://127.0.0.1:8080
      - http://127.0.0.1:9000
      - http://127.0.0.1:9060
      - http://192.168.0.159:9080
    allowed-methods: '*'
    allowed-headers: '*'
    exposed-headers: 'Authorization,Link,X-Total-Count'
    allow-credentials: true
    max-age: 1800
```

**CorsFilter in WebConfigurer.java:**

```
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = jHipsterProperties.getCors();
        if (config.getAllowedOrigins() != null && !config.getAllowedOrigins().isEmpty()) {
            log.debug("Registering CORS filter");
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/api/**", config);
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/management/**", config);
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/v2/api-docs", config);
        }
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
```

**Configurations in SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
            .antMatchers("/app/**/*.{js,html}")
            .antMatchers("/i18n/**")
            .antMatchers("/content/**")
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html")
            .antMatchers("/test/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
        .and()
            .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, CsrfFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
        .and()
            .headers()
            .contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://storage.googleapis.com; style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com data:")
        .and()
            .referrerPolicy(ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter.ReferrerPolicy.STRICT_ORIGIN_WHEN_CROSS_ORIGIN)
        .and()
            .featurePolicy("geolocation 'none'; midi 'none'; sync-xhr 'none'; microphone 'none'; camera 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; gyroscope 'none'; speaker 'none'; fullscreen 'self'; payment 'none'")
        .and()
            .frameOptions()
            .deny()
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/auth-info").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/info").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/prometheus").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
        .and()
            .oauth2Login()
        .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthorityExtractor)
                .and()
            .and()
                .oauth2Client();
        // @formatter:on
    }
```

**webpack.common.js (client app)**

```
       new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: `'${options.env}'`,
                BUILD_TIMESTAMP: `'${new Date().getTime()}'`,
                VERSION: `'${packageJson.version}'`,
                DEBUG_INFO_ENABLED: options.env === 'development',
                // The root URL for API calls, ending with a '/' - for example: `"https://www.jhipster.tech:8081/myservice/"`.
                // If this URL is left empty (""), then it will be relative to the current context.
                // If you use an API server, in `prod` mode, you will need to enable CORS
                // (see the `jhipster.cors` common JHipster property in the `application-*.yml` configurations)
                SERVER_API_URL: `'http://localhost:8080/'`
            }
        }),
```

Answer (score 2):

The OAuth 2.0 support in JHipster expects everything to be packaged in the same app and deployed as a single artifact. This is because it uses authorization code flow, which is the most secure of the OAuth 2.0 flows. It leverages Spring Security and all access tokens and ID tokens are stored on the server. A cookie is established that allows the client to talk to the server.

There's no real logic in the Angular (or React/Vue) client that knows about OAuth. In fact, the code looks very similar to session authentication.

If you really want to use a separate client, I'd recommend you use [Ionic for JHipster](https://github.com/oktadeveloper/generator-jhipster-ionic) to create your Angular client. JHipster will work with it and act as an OAuth 2.0 resource server in this scenario.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I will try Ionic for JHipster.

Answer (score 2):

As @MattRaible said, the problem is that there's no real logic in the Angular client that knows about OAuth. So, basically, you should follow these steps to solve the problem:

- Install Keycloak node module and active it in several files: angular.js, webpack.common.js and index.html
- Add a Keycloak service to interact with Keycloak server
- Add an interceptor to put our authorization token on every http request
- Tweak LogoutResource.java with minor changes.

You can find an example of this solution at this [Github repo](https://github.com/lostinsoftware/oauth2-demo). You also have an explanation in detail [here](http://www.lostinsoftware.com/2019/10/jhipster-and-oauth2-with-keycloak-separating-the-front-end-from-the-back-end/).