# Jhipster Spring boot oauth2 with separate angular does not work

Tags: angular, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak, jhipster

I generated an application with Jhipster which include angular, spring boot, keycloak with Oauth2 and it works fine. Everything is in the same repository. I need to separate the front end in a different repository where nginx will serve the static assets (js, html etc) and tomcat my API. However it does not seems possible with the current implementation of Oauth2 by Jhipster if I understand correctly everything regarding oauth2 is done on the spring boot app (redirecting to keycloack, login and token exchange) there is nothing done on the client, there is just a session cookie set by the server when the authentication is done.

The same problem is mentions here : [Separating the front-end and the API server in JHipster with OAuth2 does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57771231/separating-the-front-end-and-the-api-server-in-jhipster-with-oauth2-does-not-wor)

I would like to know why separating the front end the back-end breaks the current implementation. Is it the redirection or the cookies that causes problems ? I have a hard time figuring it out in terms of network exchanges comparing the two solutions. If someone could provide some details it would be great

Finally what are the alternatives ?

One I can see is to manage tokens on client side (ionic angular does it that's way) (which I guess is not so good, that's why Jhipster implemented it the way they did I guess) and have a stateless api acting as just a resource server. Maybe they are others ? How do jhipster does it in a micro service with multiple stateless api I dont think the front end send tokens to everybody that would be strange no ?

Thanks you for you help

Comment: As you are already using nginx to serve frontend, have you considered using it also for reverse proxying your backend?

Comment: Yes already did that with proxy pass still no luck can't finnish the authentification process